# Invoke Facebook's BigPipe onPageletArrive scripts

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to scrape information off of Facebook account settings pages for a browser app that will provide feedback to the Facebook member. I'd like to read in several pages and scrape using jQuery without displaying the pages. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting Facebook's BigPipe code to run as part of the page load using two of the three methods I've tried.

The third method below seems to work, but I'm still left wondering why the other two failed. Is there a way to trigger the BigPipe onPageletArrival scripts to run using either the jQuery .load() method or document.implementation.CreateDocument?

UPDATE: I didn't ask the core question as succinctly as I should have: How do I get either of the first two methods to behave like the iFrame method? Put another way: How do I get those BigPipe scripts to execute and fill in the content when I begin with either Attempt 1 or 2?

Attempt 1 (using document.implementation.createDocument):

```
html = getHttpPage( 'http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=basic' );
var fbPageHdr = /^<!DOCTYPE html><html[^>]+>/,
         fbPageTail = /<\/html>/;

var dt = document.implementation.createDocumentType("html", "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd");
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('','', dt);

var htmlElem = doc.createElement('html');
html = html.replace( fbPageHdr, "");
html = html.replace( fbPageTail, "");
htmlElem.innerHTML = html;
doc.appendChild( htmlElem );
```

Attempt 2 (using jQuery .load() method):

```
var $njqNode = $();
$njqNode.load('http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=basic' + ' body');
```

Attempt 3 - this one works! (using jQuery and iFrame):

```
if ($('#hiddenpage').length == 0){
   var $hiddenPage = $('<iframe id="hiddenpage" width="1000px" height="1000px"></iframe>');
   $('body').append($hiddenPage);
}
$('#hiddenpage').attr('src', 'http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=basic');
```

Answer (score 2):

BigPipe prints a static header and leaves the HTTP connection open. Additional content is added to the document out-of-order by appending javascript tags. The first two approaches don't work because they only grab the flat content of the page (which is rather unremarkable) and do not execute the BigPipe document-modifying scripts against it.

The last approach *does* work because it behaves like a new browser window.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger page updates using the first two methods to get the full content?

Comment: Not without mocking a new browser environment, which is theoretically possible, but probably impractical for your uses. Is there something wrong with using an iframe?

Comment: I'd like to turn this project into a more generic scraper tool. Unfortunately for that usage, many sites don't want to be shown in an iFrame. They object to having their content embedded in another site. There are several articles found in a quick search that describe how to detect whether a page is inside an iFrame, and how to bust out of it.